# Ubuntu 14.04 Apache 2.4.7 symfony2 site is not working Permission Denied

Tags: symfony, apache2.4

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache2.4.7 But when I tried to create the vhost it start giving me the error. after that I have put my project in the /var/www/html directory its still not accessible.

> [Thu Apr 16 09:56:38.559161 2015] [core:error] [pid 3412] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:59566] AH00035: access to /cls/web/app_dev.php denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/cls/web') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Comment: see this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451922/apache-access-denied-because-search-permissions-are-missing

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue i just have changed the permissions of the directory to 755 and it worked for me.

```
 sudo chmod 755 /to/directory
```